# ROS2 Custom Message (MSG)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To test a custom message in say my_test_package, do I need to create a separate package for this - for example, my_test_package_msg? Can I add `msg` folder at same level as `src` folder in my_test_package? If so, how I do modify CMakeLists.txt to include the header file created by custom message?

Thanks,
kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351851/ros2-custom-message-(msg)/) by [fiji3119](https://answers.ros.org/users/53083/fiji3119/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2020-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> do I need to create a separate package for this - for example, my_test_package_msg

No, but I highly recommend it. There's some CMake stuff you need to do to properly link it inside the same package that you probably don't want to deal with.

> Can I add msg folder at same level as src folder in my_test_package

You may, in fact, you must :-)

> how I do modify CMakeLists.txt to include the header file created by custom message

You may want to review https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Rosidl-Tutorial/ that'll get you squared away.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andy Blight](https://answers.ros.org/users/50920/andy-blight/) on 2020-05-18**:
The link in the answer is broken. I found this page useful: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Custom-ROS2-Interfaces/. Hope it helps!